# count occurrences of each distinct value of all columns(300 columns) in a spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe with 300 columns and each column has 10 distinct values. I need to calculate the count occurrences of distinct values for all 300 columns.

```
  --------------------------------------------------------
     col1    |  col2    | col3 ............col299   | col 300
  -------------------------------------------------------
  value11    | value21  | value31       | value300  | value 301
  value12    | value22  | value32       | value300  | value 301
  value11    | value22  | value33       | value301  | value 302
  value12    | value21  | value33       | value301  | value 302
```

If single column i calculate using below code

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.count
df.groupBy("col1").agg(count("col1")).show
```

But how to calculate efficiently for 300 columns. Please help!

Comment: if you are okay with approximate distinct count consider using efficient `approx_count_distinct`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can easily do it as mentioned below

first collect all column names and transformation as key values.
like below

**`val exprs = df.columns.map((_ -> "approx_count_distinct")).toMap`**

then simple **`df.groupBy("col1").agg(exprs)`** will provide you all columns distinct values.

**Reference**: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/sql/index.html#approx_count_distinct